# Print Date and Time In Visual Studio C++ build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, datetime, compiler-construction

How would I print the date and time for the purposes of the build. Ie: When the console for my application starts up I want to do this:

> ```
> Binary Build date: 03/03/2009 @ 10:00AM
> ```

I think this would be a super useful function for all applications to have behind the scenes for programmers, especially in a team environment.

Is there a simple way to do this using Visual Studio 2008 in C++. Thanks.

Comment: Usually you'd include a version number with your builds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use preprocessor's `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.

```
printf("Binary build date: %s @ %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
```

For making sure that cpp file that contains this code is really compiled, I use touch-utility for file as a pre-build step: touch file.cpp

Touch.bat:

```
@copy nul: /b +%1 tmp.$$$
@move tmp.$$$ %1
```

Comment: It seems that at least in VS 2005, the dependencies are calculated *before* the pre-build event, so I ended up just doing `del $(OutDir)\file.obj` in a post-build event.

Comment: I tried a bunch of different approaches and this is the one that finally worked for me.

Comment: I use `del $(IntermediateOutputPath)\$(TargetName).obj` - works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the macros `__TIME__` and `__DATE__`. Note the double underscores. These are unrolled at compile time and hence you will get the last compile time saved in your file(s).

Answer (score 3):

Note that the time and date macros only work as desired if the particular file containing them is guaranteed to be compiled during every build.

Comment: Yes, is a feature not a bug and we couldn't expect it to work any other way! How else is the compiler supposed to stamp a date if nothin's been compiled :-)

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be using the built-in `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros. From MSDN (for VS 2005):

> `__DATE__`: 
>    The compilation date of the current source file. The date is a string literal of the form Mmm dd yyyy. The month name Mmm is the same as for dates generated by the library function asctime declared in TIME.H.
>
> `__TIME__`: 
>    The most recent compilation time of the current source file. The time is a string literal of the form hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Virne's answer I created a simple header file called "BuildDate.h" with the following contents:

```
#define BUILD_DATE __DATE__ " " __TIME__
```

I touch the file using [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) touch command in my pre-build event:

```
touch.exe BuildDate.h
```

Then I include the header file in any code where I want access to the `BUILD_DATE` string. E.g.:

```
#include "BuildDate.h"
...
logger->Log("Build Date: " BUILD_DATE);
```