# Add build date (VS 2010 - C++)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Recently I built a game in XNA and in the AssemblyInfo source file I could set AssemblyVersion to x.x.* and it would set the build and revision to the date and time the project was compiled on. I am now doing a project in C++ and I am wondering how I can duplicate that functionality. Both so that the exe file displays that version and a way I can get it programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: See the answer to this question: [Print Date and Time In Visual Studio C++ build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602936/print-date-and-time-in-visual-studio-c-build)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)

Comment: they are indeed usefull, but afaik not extremely accurate: In VS you can compile a single file a.cpp, come back weeks later, change everything else, and then build the entire project. The date placed in a.obj will still be the original one.

Comment: @stijn Are you sure? (I'm interested since i use __DATE__ quite a bit) and never observed this.

Comment: I just tested it again, and yes, I'm sure it works that way. Take any dll/exe project, add
#define stringize( x ) stringizei( x )
#define stringizei( x ) #x
const char* date = "myTime" stringize(__TIME__);
to a source file, compile it, wait some time then build. Open the executable in a text editor and look for "myTime", you will see the original time.

Comment: btw a nice way to do this is using a pre-build or post-build event in which you somehow inject the date/time into the build. I use a pre-build event that calls an executable that sets date, time and VCS version number in the AssemblyInfo (or a version resource for C++). Another way is: always rebuild ;]

Comment: With regards to accuracy during standard builds, you usually don't care until you're ready to ship the product. At that point you will do a clean build anyway and everything will auto update. But I do agree that prebuild events are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add **DATE** macro is a good solution I believe.

```
The compilation date of the current source file. The date is a string literal of the form Mmm dd yyyy. The month name Mmm is the same as for dates generated by the library function asctime declared in TIME.H.
```