# C++ VS2017 define macro using command substitution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, preprocessor

I am trying to create my own macro by adding this parameter to additional command line options:

```
/DSEED=$(Get-Date -UFormat "%S")
```

Which ( I think ) is equivalent to:

```
-DSEED=$(date +%S)  (if using gcc)
```

I might be completely wrong, and if that is the case, how could I create a macro (if possible) that gets the current time and then maybe format it.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602936/print-date-and-time-in-visual-studio-c-build) the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: @lakeweb I want to create my own macro, by using shell command substition.. `__TIME__` and `__DATE__` don't suffice my needs.