# Preprocessor Timestamp

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, xcode

Is it possible to generate an embedded Unix timestamp via a preprocessor macro?

For instance: `#define VERSION_EXPIRE __TIMESTAMP__`

The reason for this is, that i have beta versions and i want to generate an expire timestamp on compile time (in a special build configuration).

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771/output-compile-time-stamp-in-visual-c-executable .  But since you need a Unix timestamp, the difficulty is to convert the value returned by the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros to Unix format while still within preprocessing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved it as follows:

```
#define VERSION_TIMESTAMP __DATE__" "__TIME__"\x0"
```

In some other class

```
+ (NSDate *)versionExpiresInDays:(NSUInteger)days {
    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:VERSION_TIMESTAMP];   
    NSLocale *enLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
    NSDate *compiledOn = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:dateString locale:enLocale];

    return [compiledOn dateByAddingTimeInterval:days*24*60*60];
}
```

Comment: The drawback with this is that you must not forget to clean the target every time, because otherwise the precompiled stuff won't change!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd use versioning software like `svn` or `git` you may have automatic replacement of strings like `$Id: $` or `$Date: $` by the id or date of the particular version of the file (svn) or of the "HEAD" release (git).

**Edit:** For `git` you can extract the sources

```
git archive --format=zip -9 -o project.zip HEAD file1 file2...
```

To replace certain strings during that process you have to tell git in `.gitattributes` that you want to have things substituted:

```
file*   export-subst
```

For the syntax of what and how terms between "$...$", please refer to the formats in the man page of `git-log`. Just as examples I have in my code

```
#define P99_VERSION_DATE "$Format:%cd$"
#define P99_VERSION_ID "$Format:%H$"
```

Which in the distribution version of the file is

```
#define P99_VERSION_DATE "Thu Oct 7 23:38:43 2010 +0200"
#define P99_VERSION_ID "6f9740a6808ff50f42d24bb7b5234a904f84e6fe"
```

Comment: I had not realized this. Could you refer me to the documentation for this (i use git)?

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom build step before preprocessing that uses sed to replace `__TIMESTAMP__` with `date`.  The easiest way to do this is to [tell Xcode to use a makefile](http://web.ist.utl.pt/jose.alberto.coelho/mac/MakefilesXcode.pdf).