# Is it possible to get current time at compile time?

Tags: c++, timestamp, c++14, constexpr

I'm thinking about using current timestamp as a piece of version. I would like to retrieve that information at compile time. So ideally I would like to do:

```
constexpr long long currentTimestamp = getCurrentTimestamp();
```

Is that possible with C++14?

Comment: At best, it would be by Translation Unit...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [standard](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) C `__TIME__` macro with `__DATE__` macro.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771/output-compile-time-stamp-in-visual-c-executable) question for an example.

Comment: Close, but I do need full date, not only hours.

Comment: @freakish: Then use `__DATE__` too. Why don't you click on the link and read the documentation?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Interesting, although parsing textual date might be a pain. Are there standard tools for that? But I guess I'll do that if there's no better option.

Comment: @freakish: Using "build time" as your project's version seems like a strange thing to do. What if you rebuild the same revision later? How will you distinguish major.minor branches? Why don't you use a more conventional version scheme? Do it in your build system and pass the resulting number/string/whatever through to your code as a macro using `-D`

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I am using major.minor branches. It's a *piece* of version, not entire version. I just want to have this additional info in the version itself.

Comment: Just a note: These macros return values per translation unit!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition it's pretty common to use timestamp as part of the versioning scheme, for instance .NET assemblies use such a scheme for automatic "build numbers".

Comment: @zett42: A version control revision number is more conventional. I'm not going to start considering what .NET does as any sort of best practice ;) (It's nice to have "build date" in the executable somewhere but only as non-normative information; again, you can rebuild an old version at any time)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "A version control revision number is more conventional." This does not matter.

Answer (score 12):

Use `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` or `__TIMESTAMP__`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("date: '%s'\n", __DATE__);
    printf("time: '%s'\n", __TIME__);
    printf("timestamp: '%s'\n", __TIMESTAMP__);
}
```

[Output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f9a9aad5d9962ef):

```
date: 'May  5 2017'
time: '00:29:26'
timestamp: 'Fri May  5 00:29:26 2017'
```

However, you will need to make sure that the file is recompiled for obvious reasons.

From [gcc online docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html):

> `__DATE__`
>
> This macro expands to a string constant that describes the date on which the preprocessor is being run. The string constant contains
>   eleven characters and looks like "Feb 12 1996". If the day of the
>   month is less than 10, it is padded with a space on the left.
>
> `__TIME__`
>
> This macro expands to a string constant that describes the time at which the preprocessor is being run. The string constant contains
>   eight characters and looks like "23:59:01".
>
> `__TIMESTAMP__`
>
> This macro expands to a string constant that describes the date and time of the last modification of the current source file. The
>   string constant contains abbreviated day of the week, month, day of
>   the month, time in hh:mm:ss form, year and looks like "Sun Sep 16
>   01:03:52 1973". If the day of the month is less than 10, it is padded
>   with a space on the left.

Note, that `__TIMESTAMP__` is not standard and some compilers might not support it.

Comment: Except  TIMESTAMP is not standardized; and might not be supported on other compilers.

Comment: @HansOlsson perhaps. But it works on gcc and ms compilers.